# Changing string value to a date time in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, scatter-plot

```
import plotly.express as px
string_to_convert = df['Date_Sampled'][(df.Platform == "Facebook")]
new_date = pd.to_datetime(string_to_convert)


x = new_date
y = df['Likes_Followers_Visits_Downloads'][(df.Platform == "Facebook")]
df = px.data.tips()
fig = px.scatter(df, x, y, trendline="ols")
fig.show()
```

I tried to convert my Date_Sampled to datetime, but I still got the error:

```
KeyError: 'Date_Sampled'
```

How can I convert it?

Comment: Your dataframe seems to lack 'Date_Sampled' key. Please print out df.columns and check if its there

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you dataframe has the Date_Sampled column and it's better to use

```py
string_to_convert = df['Date_Sampled'][(df['Platform'] == "Facebook")]
```

instead of:

```py
string_to_convert = df['Date_Sampled'][(df.Platform == "Facebook")]
```